# Disable times already booked (with DateTimePicker, Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, forms, datetime, material-ui, datetimepicker

I'm trying to disable the times that can't be used to make an appointment, so far I've managed to disable the days but not the precise times. Basically I would like to keep active the ability to click on the desired day but then I don't want to give the possibility to book at a time already taken (preferably marked in red). Appointments can be made between 09:00 and 17:30 Monday to Friday

ps: I have disabled the possibility of inserting the time via text, it is only possible by clicking on the calendar (it's not visible here)

This is the component:

```
<DateTimePicker
                    disablePast
                    inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
                    minutesStep={30}
                    minTime={dayjs('2018-01-01T09:00')}
                    maxTime={dayjs('2018-01-01T17:30')}
                    renderDay={disableSpecificDays}
                    shouldDisableDate={disableWeekends}
                    shouldDisableTime={disableSpecificTimes}
                    value={booking.bookingDate}
                    onChange={(newValue) => { dispatch(b.setBookingDate(newValue)) }}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
```

these are the days to disable:

```
const datesToDisable= ["2022-12-19T00:00:00.000Z", "2022-12-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z", "2022-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"]
```

this is the function to disable the days (dunno if I can add here the possibility to disable times):

```
const disableSpecificDays = (date: dayjs.Dayjs, selectedDates: dayjs.Dayjs[], pickersDayProps: PickersDayProps<dayjs.Dayjs>
    ): JSX.Element => {
        const stringifiedDate = dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        const dates = datesToDisable.map((day) => { return day.slice(0, 10) })
        if (dates.includes(stringifiedDate)) {
            return <PickersDay {...pickersDayProps} disabled />
        }
        return <PickersDay {...pickersDayProps} />
    }
```

these are the times booked:

```
const timesBooked= ["2022-12-30T15:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-03T10:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-04T17:00:00.000Z", "2023-01-05T09:00:00.000Z"]
```

Should I disable the times of those specific days by using this function called in "shouldDisableTime"? If I can, I have no idea how to do it...

```
const disableSpecificTimes = (timeValue: number, clockType: ClockPickerView): boolean => {
         //something here maybe?
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found help from a user on github and he guided me to the solution I post here:

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DateTimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker";
import { ClockPickerView } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";

const datesToDisable = [
  "2022-12-19T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"
];

const timesBooked = [
  "2022-12-30T15:30:00.000Z",
  "2023-01-03T10:30:00.000Z",
  "2023-01-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-01-05T09:00:00.000Z"
];

const disabledTimes = timesBooked.map((dateTime) => dayjs(dateTime));

const shouldDisableDay = (day: Dayjs) => {
  if (day.day() === 0 || day.day() === 6) {
    return true;
  }
  return datesToDisable.includes(day.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss[Z]"));
};

export default function BasicDateTimePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);

  const shouldDisableTime = React.useCallback(
    (time: number, clockType: ClockPickerView) => {
      const selectedDay = value.date();
      if (disabledTimes.some((disabled) => disabled.date() === selectedDay)) {
        if (clockType === "minutes" || clockType === "hours") {
          return disabledTimes.some(
              (disabledTime) =>
                  disabledTime.date() === selectedDay &&
                  disabledTime.hour() - 1 === value.hour() &&
                  disabledTime.minute() === time
          )
      }
      }
      return false;
    },
    [value]
  );

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DateTimePicker
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
        label="DateTimePicker"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        disablePast
        minutesStep={30}
        shouldDisableDate={shouldDisableDay}
        shouldDisableTime={shouldDisableTime}
        ampm={false}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Here the link of the post on github
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/7167

You can also check this live working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-day-and-time-disabling-74vveq